# Email attachments in document library

Tags: sharepoint-email

We have a document library.  Staff has dumped email messages (.msg files) in the library.  I can create a view to display the emails.  Is there a way to create the view and also indicate there might be an attachment to the email?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using? Go into List Settings -> Click on the view you're using and tick the box next to Attachments. This will show filles attached to list items, but that might not work for attachments within the email message.

Comment: No, the OOTB attachments column will not work for this.  I don't think this can be done.

Comment: SharePoint 2013.  And it is not actually a list, but a document Library.  Can I create a list which looks at the .msg files only in the document library?  Also, when I create a list I do not see the "Attachments" box to check.

Comment: This can be done with some Client Side Rendering. Is JavaScript an option for you?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could think of would be to show the File Size column.  Messages with no attachment will be much smaller.